# Safari can't save the file. Safari can't save the file "file.jpg" to the downloads folder

Tags: macos, finder, safari, permission, file

Safari on macOS suddenly cannot save common image files on any website. It instead shows the error:

[image: Safari can't save the file.]

> Safari can't save the file.
> Safari can't save the file "file.jpg" to the downloads folder.
> OK

The Mac and Downloads folder have plenty of free disc space.

What is wrong with Safari and how can I fix this error?

Comment: Is this happening with any/all image files from many sites or just one site in particular?

Comment: All image files, all websites.

Comment: What about a regular download like a Zip file?

Comment: Can you try Control-clicking on the image and try saving to a different folder by clicking `Save Image As...` (recommend your home folder, `/Users/<insert username>` or just `~/`) and see if that works? If it's a link that's set up to download the image then the menu option would be `Save Linked File As...`